# HTTP Get command doesn't work in (GSM/WCDMA) dongle network. Gives an HTTP server unreachable error while executing it

Tags: 4d-database

4DV16R6 HTTP Get command doesn't work in (GSM/WCDMA) dongle network whereas it smoothly runs over Ethernet/Wifi network. In dongle network, it gives "HTTP server unreachable" error when executing HTTP Get command.

I've also tested with IC TCP/IP command of 4DV16R6 (i.e. TCP_Open, TCP_Send,...) in the same (dongle network) - it just works fine.

Plus, I've also got a chance to test this on 4DV17 to the latest R2 release - same issue (HTTP server unreachable error). But in 4DV15 or all below versions - it is working fine.

It seems that from 4DV16 onwards some upgrades must have been the issue which is causing it...?

Apart from this, I tried to went an extra mile doing packet sniffing while executing HTTP Get command - strange that the issue occurs before sending any packets to the dest. server i.e. no packets were even sending for request but the error message "HTTP server unreachable" popped up.

Can somebody please figure out what's going on?

For testing I have used the simple HTTP Get codes:

C_TEXT(URLPic_t)
 URLPic_t:="http://www.4d.com/sites/all/themes/dimention/images/home/logo4D.jpg"
 ARRAY TEXT(HeaderNames_at;0)
 ARRAY TEXT(HeaderValues_at;0)
 C_PICTURE(Pic_i)
 $httpResponse:=HTTP Get(URLPic_t;Pic_i;HeaderNames_at;HeaderValues_at)

**Update**: Let me explain my few research on this so that it would help everyone to know what is happening.

I've also tested this on various networks (say Ethernet, WiFi or even mobile Hotspot). HTTP Get works fine over all these networks as they all have their physical (mac) addresses. But the problem in the (GSM/WCDMS) dongle network is that it doesn't have any physical (mac) address as this is a Cellular based device (modem) rather it has an IMEI no. like any other phone or modem has.

So my assumption is HTTP Get command is failing over cellular based devices network (or works OK over non-cellular devices like above).

I wonder if anyone could try this on any Cellular based device network and see the result.

Also, using phone's network (as a WIFI) from it's hotspot in PC would be pretty same case like you use your direct WIFI network of which it works successfuly. As the PC uses its WIFI interface (which have physical mac address) enabled in order to communicate packets and thus works OK in that way as well.

Though this is just an assumption from my finding it could be other reason that causing this issue (not sure)?

I hope now this will give a bit details about the real scenario that Im facing with any HTTP Client commands (say HTTP Get or HTTP Request) from 4Dv16 and higher versions.

Comment: Can someone please help me on this? I'm needing this as an urgent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with 4Dv17 e 4Dv17r3 on UMTS and LTE and it works fine.

I can advise to check if there is a DNS problem on you GSM connection: you can check that using an ip address instead of host name in the url (but not on that url on 4d.com because it doesn't accept the ip)

**Update**:
I found a fixed bug that could resolve your problem:

`ACI0098213 'HTTP Get' command fails on Windows system and returns unexpectedly the error #30 ("HTTP Server unreachable") for some web sites.`

cfr https://bugs.4d.fr/fixedbugslist?Version=17.0_HF3

Comment: Hi Umberto, it is working with IC TCP/IP commands so I don't think there is any issue with network connection in dongle. Also to confirm more, the same HTTP Get command works in 4DV15 or below versions in the Same network connection.

Comment: With using direct IP instead DNS name, it still pops up the same error.

Comment: I've already tried on 4Dv17, HF1, HF2 and in R2 as well. Didn't work on those either. The issue is not only in HTTP Get command but also in HTTP Request command. So wondering as if any 4D engineer can confirm if this is a bug or some other issue that might causing it...

Comment: Hi Ravi, did you tried 17 HF3? The bug is fixed in the HF3 list

Comment: Hi Umberto, I don't have 4Dv17HF3 installer so haven't tried yet. Instead I've tried on the latest 4Dv17 release (i.e. 4Dv17R2 current one) - but like I said - didn't work at all. Could you pass me a link for 4Dv17HF3 installer? I'll give a shot though.. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Umberto, I managed to test this issue on 4Dv17HF3 as well. But it didn't work on that either. So I presume this is a bug which still persists on 4Dv16 to current one (4Dv17 and it's minor as well as major updates)...

Comment: Can someone please help me to get this sort out. I have an application with a web service enable for data syncing. So command like HTTP client are frequently being used. I'm stuck in the middle of my upgrade development... to deliver my clients.

Currently, 4D has a new release 4Dv17 but this bug still persists in it too. So any 4D engineer (Tim Penner or someone) could you please have look on this?

Thanks.